# How to remove Async storage warning from react native

Tags: android, react-native, asyncstorage

Dependencies i used

"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.1",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^8.1.0",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
"firebase": "^9.6.7",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.3",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.1",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-maps": "^0.31.1",
"react-native-no-internet-screen": "^1.0.4",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.1.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
"validator": "^13.7.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "7.17.5",
"@babel/runtime": "7.17.2",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
"babel-jest": "26.6.3",
"eslint": "7.14.0",
"jest": "26.6.3",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
"react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
},

Comment: What warning do you get?

Comment: Question is unclear. Add the warning you are getting and possibly attach a screenshot of the warning or paste it inside the question along with your dependencies.